# removing vertices with no edges in graphx spark

Tags: scala, network-programming, spark-graphx

I was wondering if somebody could help, I'm having a problem with a function written for graphx in spark which keeps giving error messages if I have vertices with no edges.

When joining edges and vertices together

```
val graph = Graph(vertices, edges)
```

is there a simple way to skip over vertices which do not have any corresponding edges? or is there a way of subgraphing for this? Currently if I use subgraph for say an edge attribute, it preserves the vertices.

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

`val graph = Graph(vertices, edges)`  <---this one got an error? maybe you should give the type of VD and Ed, like `val graph:Graph[Int, Int] = Graph(vertices, edges)`.

In fact, vextice with no edges is ok. I have tried with 10 vertices and two of which has no edges.